# Accept Macbook Touchbar typing suggestions with keyboard

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

I mostly type using my external keyboard while my Macbook Pro is sitting on my desk, away from my hands. Sometimes I'd like to accept the Touchbar typing suggestions, but it's more work to get my fingers to the Touchbar and back than it is to finish typing the word, no matter how long or contrived.

Is there a way to accept suggestions with a keyboard shortcut? I didn't find such an option within MacOS preferences, I'm hoping I just missed it.

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/389152/151404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Apple documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh27071/11.0/mac/11.0):

> Touch Bar typing suggestions
>
> If your Mac has a Touch Bar, enable this option to display typing
> suggestions in the Touch Bar as you type.
>
> While typing, you can display a list of suggested words onscreen by
> pressing F5 (you may need to also press the Fn key, depending on your
> Mac model).

Comment: Uncomfortable (I do need to press the Fn key on my external keyboard) but works, thanks.